# Mule MUnit test with Maven, mule.home property is not defined

Tags: maven, mule, munit

In our Mule projects we have a common properties file that is referenced from a number of Mule projects. To do this we put the file in the Mule installation directory and reference it in a flow in each project:

```
<spring:beans>
    <context:property-placeholder
    location="file:///${mule.home}/conf/common.properties" />
</spring:beans>
```

This works fine for running the projects in Mule and from Anypoint Studio as in both cases `mule.home` is defined. It also works for running the MUnit test suites defined in the project from Anypoint Studio.

However when running the tests from Maven `mule.home` is not defined and the tests fail. I've tried adding a definition to `mule.home` to the Maven `settings.xml` file, but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how I can run the tests from Maven and keep the `mule.home` reference in the property flow? Or perhaps is there a way to have an alternative configuration in the property flow for when the flow is called from the test suite?

Alternatively how should we reference a common property file from multiple Mule projects?

Versions:
Mule runtime: 3.6.2

Munit: 1.1.0

Maven 3.3.1

Comment: FYI `${mule.home}/conf` is on the classpath so you don't need to access it with an absolute file reference. You should be able to load it with `classpath:common.properties`

Comment: No such luck `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [common.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: Really? When running in Mule?

Comment: This common file is outside of the project right ? That's why is not in the classpath. I think your only option is to force it via jvm argument like -Dmule.home=yourpath, it should work.

Comment: Or what I was trying to get the OP at: load the file as a classpath resource and provide properly via Maven, for example via a shared JAR. Loading a file with an absolute path like this should be avoided.

Comment: Despite I answered to this question, I do agree with David, avoid this practice, there is nothing bad in replicating the file in your apps and have it common does not really help you save time, just look at how many questions you are posting :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mvn -Dmule.home=yourpath test
```

This should do the trick.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set mule.home programmatically perhaps in a parent Abstract test class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("mule.home", "whatever");
}
```